# Open an address, present in a website, directly in Smartphone GPS App as destination

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have an address (city, street and number) saved in my website.
I would like to use it as destination of a GPS navigation app installed on a Smartphone. I think that right solution should be "sending" this address to GoogleMaps application installed on the smartphone and set it as destination. How to obtain this?

Is there some specific API that allows me to set Destination address in GPS App, retrieving it from a website opened in a browser?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set an URL like this (start point, end point and type of navigation where it's drive here), the Android system will ask you if you want to launch Google Maps App :

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Postkoetslaan&daddr=Rotterdam&dirflg=d

Comment: Hi Aurelien, I just tried with my Samsung S4 Mini and..... it opens Google Maps website inside Firefox.... not the standalone app....

Comment: the system should ask you if you want to open the browser or the app... could you tried with an other phone.